# how to find snap point when mouse is closed to any object in three.js or from the scene?

Tags: three.js

Actually, I'm find the intersect point of any object which are added into the scene and also I am getting the the intersect point when mouse point is overlaps on objects using ray cater but now I want to find the intersection point of object when mouse point
is some away from any object of scene?? r we can say simply, when mouse  point goes near to any objects then find that object and draw snap.

Comment: You could create 4 or more raycasts a few pixels away from the mouse (top, down, left, right) so you can see what's "near" the mouse pointer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a code sample of your best effort to solve the problem so far.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.